# How can I install gazette in elementary OS 0.4 Loki?

Tags: software-installation

I can't install gazette the weather widget. I tried this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gotwig/weekly
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gazette
```

The first and second commands worked but the third command shows this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gazette
```

Answer (score 4):

The PPA you are trying to install Gazette from has not been updated to include a build for Loki (Ubuntu Xenial). It appears that the Gazette project does not offer prebuilt binaries, so your only option is to build from source.

Launchpad is currently down, so these instructions need checking.

1. Install pre-requisite packages (check the `INSTALL` file for specifics): `sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake`
2. Grab the code: `bzr branch lp:gazette`
3. From inside the project directory, generate configure file: `./autogen.sh`
4. Compile like normal: `./configure && make && sudo make install`.

Comment: sorry but i'm a new user i just cant understand how to do

Comment: @emad I'm afraid the answer is probably that you'll have to wait until someone builds Gazette for Loki then I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the ppa first to see which packages includes using synaptic.

*Detailed instructions here:
HOW TO LIST PACKAGES FROM A PPA / REPOSITORY IN UBUNTU
Source: 
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-list-packages-from-ppa.html?m=1

Comment: This does not answer the original question of how to install Gazette on Loki.

Comment: For instructions about installing gazette you can try https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/how-can-i-install-gazette-widget.339/ but I haven't tried in loki. I assumed there was a problem with the repository name so I apologize if my answer could lead to confussion.